# HTML Force download mp3 file in 2023

Tags: html, download, mp3

Is it possible in 2023 download a file .mp3 directly?
At these days browsers plays song on the browser, i need to download it!

Is there some workaround? JS is ok for me.

**this not work:**

```
<a href="https://link_mp3.mp3" download="name_file.mp3">Download!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, the `download` attribute only works for downloading from the same origin, perhaps that's your issue?

Nevertheless there are a few alternative ways to approach this:

**Approach 1, with `fetch` and download in JavaScript:**

```
function downloadBlob(blob, filename) {
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.download = filename;
      a.href = blob;
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      a.remove();
    }

function downloadResourceFromUrl(url) {
  filename = url.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();
  fetch(url, {
      mode: 'no-cors'
    })
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      let blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      downloadBlob(blobUrl, filename);
    });
}
```

And then in your HTML call the `downloadResourceFromUrl` method when clicking your anchor:

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:downloadResourceFromUrl('https://www.yoursite.com/name_file.mp3')">Download!</a>
```

**Approach 2, force download from your backend (if you have one) with headers:**

If you're returning the file from your backend, you can try adding the following headers to whatever endpoint returns your file:

- Content-Type: application/octet-stream
- Content-Description: File Transfer
- Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=your_file.mp3

Comment: Thank you for reply Jarmo. I've try Approach 1, now i can download the file but it is 0KB! Do you have any idea?  -  Instead i don't have a backend in this case, so i can try with Approach 2.

Comment: @Marco probably because you don't have proper CORS headers set, try changing the fetch `mode` parameter to `cors` or `same-origin`